# Populating ListBox with List of <class> VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list, class, listbox

I have a class called optionCode:

```
Class optionCode
    Public description As String
    Public optCode As String
End Class
```

I have a query the returns a list of this optionCode class:

```
Dim _SelectActiveOptionCodes2 = (From _OptCodes In _EntityModel.tblOptionCodes
                                Where _OptCodes.fdStatus = "A"
                                Select New optionCode With {.description = _OptCodes.fdDescription,
                                                            .optCode = _OptCodes.fdOptionCode}).ToList()
```

I want to use this list to populate a listbox where the description is the display field and the option code is the value field.

When using:

```
sortableOptionCodes = _SelectActiveOptionCodes2
sortedOptionCodes = _SelectActiveOptionCodes2
OptionCodeListBox.DataSource = sortedOptionCodes
```

The listbox populates, but every entry is "OptionCodeSearch.Form1+optionCode"

I can't figure out how to use the .ValueMember and .DisplayMember functions to get the listbox to load the way I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` work off properties: `Gets or sets the property to use as the actual value for the items in the System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.` So your class should use Properties not Fields (there are conditions where Fields are treated/handled differently than Properties).

With such classes, it good idea to override ToString so you can specify the default text to display instead of the Type (`OptionCodeSearch.Form1+optionCode`):

```
Class optionCode
    Public PROPERTY description As String
    Public PROPERTY optCode As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Description       ' ????
    End Function
End Class
```

`ValueMember` is typically a numeric, but otherwise once you have the `List(of optionCode)` `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are used to tell the `ListBox` the *Property Names*:

```
OptionCodeListBox.DisplayMember = "description"
OptionCodeListBox.ValueMember = "optCode"
```

---

Not for nothing, but primitives like that can be made into a generic use-almost-anywhere class:

```
Public Class Element(Of T)
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Value As T

    Friend Sub New(n As String, v As T)
        Name = n
        Value = v
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function

End Class
```

`Of T` allows you to define the Value data type when you build it:

```
Dim el As New Element(Of Integer)(textName, intValue)
```

Your list would then be:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Element(Of Integer))
```

It is a little cumbersome to iterate lists, but VS/Intellisense provide hints:

```
For Each El As Element(of Integer) in myList(Of Element(Of Integer))
```

If you are using one of these a lot in a project, you can subclass it:

```
Public Class optCode
    Inherits Element(Of String)
```

Now, the whole `Element(Of String)` part is built into your new `optCode` class, making it easier to type, use and remember.

The value of these is that you can use the same class for a collection of Name-Value pairs of string, datetime, integer, decimal etc without coding a new class each time you need something like it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the extra effort to expand my programming knowledge. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer is for the web form control. See Plutonix's answer for the windows form control.

I believe what you are looking for are the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties of the `ListBox`.

```
OptionCodeListBox.DataTextField = "description"
OptionCodeListBox.DataValueField = "optCode"
```