# Need Help properly displaying an array in a listbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, listbox

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim Teams() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("SBWinners.txt")
        Dim Team As String
        Dim SteelersWins As Integer = 0
        Dim RaidersWins As Integer = 0
        Dim PackersWins As Integer = 0
        Dim CowboysWins As Integer = 0
        Dim GiantsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim RamsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim RavensWins As Integer = 0
        Dim SaintsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim FortyNinersWins As Integer = 0
        Dim RedskinsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim BroncosWins As Integer = 0
        Dim PatriotsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim ColtsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim DolphinsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim BearsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim JetsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim ChiefsWins As Integer = 0
        Dim BuccWins As Integer = 0

        For Each team In Teams
            If team = "Steelers" Then
                SteelersWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Raiders" Then
                RaidersWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Packers" Then
                PackersWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Cowboys" Then
                CowboysWins += 1
            End If
            If Team = "Giants" Then
                GiantsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Rams" Then
                RamsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Ravens" Then
                RavensWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Saints" Then
                SaintsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Forty-Niners" Then
                FortyNinersWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Redskins" Then
                RedskinsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Broncos" Then
                BroncosWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Patriots" Then
                PatriotsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Colts" Then
                ColtsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Dolphins" Then
                DolphinsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Bears" Then
                BearsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Jets" Then
                JetsWins += 1
            End If
            If Team = "Chiefs" Then
                ChiefsWins += 1
            End If
            If team = "Buccaneers" Then
                BuccWins += 1
            End If
        Next

        Dim Wins() As Integer = {SteelersWins, RaidersWins, PackersWins, CowboysWins, GiantsWins, RamsWins, RavensWins, SaintsWins, FortyNinersWins, RedskinsWins,
            BroncosWins, PatriotsWins, ColtsWins, DolphinsWins, BearsWins, JetsWins, ChiefsWins, BuccWins}

        For Each win In Wins
            Array.Sort(Wins)
            Array.Reverse(Wins)
            lstOutput.Items.Add(win)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

What I have right now is code that reads a text file with the names of Superbowl winners, and counts the number of wins by the number of times the team name appears. These wins are then put into an array and sorted in descending order and displayed in a listbox. This all works fine.

My problem is that I need to display the corresponding team name with their number of wins on the same line in the listbox. So, instead of being:

6

5

5

4

4

It needs to be:

6 Steelers

5 49ers

5 Cowboys

4 Giants

4 Packers

And so on.

Comment: The listbox doesnt know the names of the variables the data came from.  You need a class to keep the name with the count and add that to the ListBox.  [Populating ListBox with List(Of class)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25449848/1070452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code, not the least of which is you are using hard coded names and variables to collect your team information. This is severely limiting if new names are added or names change.

As Plutonix mentioned in the comments you need to use a class to properly identify and collate your information. I also strongly suggest you use a List(of T) collection to contain your data.

The following code does what you desire.

```
Private Class cls_Team_wins
    Public Team_Name As String
    Public Wins As Integer
    Public Sub New(Name As String)
        Team_Name = Name
        Wins = 1
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Strings.Right("  " & Wins, 2) & " - " & Team_Name
    End Function
End Class


Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim Games = New List(Of cls_Team_wins)
    Dim Teams() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("SBWinners.txt")

    For Each Team As String In Teams
        If Team <> "" Then
            Dim Team_Win As cls_Team_wins = Games.Find(Function(x) x.Team_Name = Team)
            If Team_Win Is Nothing Then
                Games.Add(New cls_Team_wins(Team))
            Else
                Team_Win.Wins += 1
            End If
        End If

    Next

    Games.Sort(Function(x, y) -x.Wins.CompareTo(y.Wins))

    ListBox1.DataSource = Games

End Sub
```

The class included the team name and win counter. It over-rides the ToString method so the list box knows what to show as text. The New function requires you pass the team name and presets the win counter to one.

The For Loop checks for and ignores blank team names, this can be an issue reading text files, esp on the last line. Otherwise it will either add a new team to the list if it does not already exist, or it will increment the win counter if it does.

Once the list is built it is reverse sorted (Note the minus sign in the "Function" compare statement, that's a little trick that reverses the sort), and finally given to the listbox as a datasource.

Good luck to you :)